# Jquery ajax call wrong payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some troubles whit jquery ajax call, infact I tried to perform a post call passing like data a string variable:

```
 myVar = 'Hello';

  $.ajax(
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data:  myVar,
     success : function(data) {

     },
     complite: function() {...},
     error: function(err) {...}
  )
```

If I inspect the http call I can see that the payload is:

```
  'Hello': ""
```

I don't know how it is possible and how fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery, by default, will put a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header on data it sends via Ajax.

You, however, are passing a plain text string.

---

You need to either change the `Content-Type` to match the data you are sending or the data you are sending to match the `Content-Type`. (Or you could change both).

The important things are:

- **The data and content-type need to match**
- **The server needs to be able to handle data in the format you are sending**

---

So you might:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data:  myVar,
     contentType: 'text/plain'
     // ...
 })
```

or, since jQuery will encode objects as URL encoded data:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data:  { myVar },
     // ...
 })
```

or, if you want multipart data:

```
 const data = new FormData();
 data.append('myVar', myVar);

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data,
     contentType: false // XHR will read the content-type from the FormData object (which it needs to do in order to determine the boundary paramater), putting 'false' here stops jQuery overriding it
     // ...
 })
```

or, for JSON

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data:  JSON.stringify(myVar), // This will be a JSON text representing a string
     contentType: 'application/json'
     // ...
 })
```

Comment: [Doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem. Is the content-type not set in the request? Is the request body wrong? Is the server side code you haven't shared with us unable to parse the data when it has the correct content-type and format?

Comment: My fault, the code is more complicated then I wrote and I didn't pass contentType to real ajax call.  So putting contentType resolve the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are passing payload in the wrong formate.

```
myVar = 'Hello';

$.ajax(
     type: 'POST',
     url : 'https://...',
     data: {
        'name':myVar
        },
     success : function(data) {

     },
     complite: function() {...},
     error: function(err) {...}
  )
```

On the server side you will get the value in the key 'name' you can fetch the value using 'name' key.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, as the jquery docs say data type can be a String, anyway I try solution and this time payolad is  "{ 'name':  'Hello'}": ""